# node.js http request hangs instead of error/timeout when network unavailble

Tags: node.js, http, request, adb, http-proxy

I am trying to implement http requests with the following enabled:

- HEAD, GET & POST methods
- Set proxy dynamically with each request
- Set proxy by domain
- http, https, socks5 protocols
- accept types: application/xml & application/json
- content-types: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, application/json
- Clear cookies dynamically for specific domains

All of the above can be satisfied using ajax requests in chrome browser (with the addition of chrome runtime features to manage cookies, PAC scripts to handle proxy requirements etc)

However, I also need to create a standalone version in node.js that does not use a browser. To date I've attempted to use restler, axios, http/https and request libraries. So far the request library looks the most promising (though I note it has recently been deprecated). Sample code for a HEAD request with a socks5 proxy:

```
var request = require('request');
var httpAgent = require('socks5-http-client/lib/Agent');

var url = 'http://www.example.com';

var requestOptions = { 
    timeout: 5000,
    //proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:8888", //http proxy
    agentClass: httpAgent, //socks5 proxy
    agentOptions: {
        socksHost: "127.0.0.1",
        socksPort: 4001
    }
};

request.head(url,requestOptions,function (err, res, html) {
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) console.log(res.headers);
    else if (!err) console.log('status code: ' + res.statusCode);
    else {
        if (['ETIMEDOUT','ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'].indexOf(err.code) > -1) console.log("timeout");
        else console.log(err);
    }
});
```

This works fine most of the time - I can choose to set the proxy in the headers based on the url domain, and I can read the status code and headers when successful.

However, one type of proxy I run involves port forwarding requests via android debug bridge to a connected phone running a proxy server, e.g.:

```
adb forward tcp:4001 tcp: 8080 
//4001 - local port
//8080 - proxy server port running on phone
```

If the network on the phone is unavailable, the request will hang forever and won't return an error, or even end successfully if the network restores (only unplugging the phone to end the port forwarding triggers a request error).
Using req.end() and req.abort() has not fixed this either.